# Finding maximum likelihood estimator of sample of geometric RV's

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I have a sample of geometric random variables $X_1,… ,X_n$ and I am interested in finding the maximum likelihood estimator for such a sample.

Hence we have the corresponding PMF $$f_X(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}(1- \frac{1}{\theta})^{x-1}$$
whereby $x\geq1$ and $\theta \geq 1$.

Im looking to find the maximum likelihood estimator so first I calculate the likelihood function and the log likelihood function.

$$\begin{aligned}\mathcal{L}_X(\theta) &= \prod^n_{i=1}\left[\frac{1}{\theta}\left(1- \frac{1}{\theta} \right)^{x_i-1}\right] \\ &= \theta^{-n} \left(1- \frac{1}{\theta} \right)^{n\bar{x}-n} \end{aligned}$$

And the log likelihood as

$$\begin{aligned}\ell_X(\theta) &= -n\log(\theta)+(n\bar{x}-n) \log\left(\frac{\theta-1}{\theta} \right) \\ &= -n\log(\theta)+(n\bar{x}-n)\log(\theta-1)-(n\bar{x}-n)\log(\theta) \end{aligned}$$

Then I differentiate the log likelihood function and equate it to $0$ to get critical points of the funcion

$$\ell'_X(\theta)=\frac{n\bar{x}-n}{\theta-1}-\frac{n\bar{x}}{\theta}=0$$
from here I arrive at
$$\begin{aligned} \frac{n\bar{x}-n}{\theta-1} &= \frac{n\bar{x}}{\theta} \\ 1-\frac{1}{\bar{x}} &= 1-\frac{1}{\theta} \\ \theta &= \bar{x}\end{aligned}$$

Then I take the Second derivative of the log likelihood function and plug my critical value to see if its negative.
$$\ell''_X(\theta)=-\frac{n\bar{x}-n}{(\theta-1)^2}+\frac{n\bar{x}}{\theta^2}$$

From here Im stuck as I cant tell by plugging this value whether the function will always be negative hence indicating a maximum.
$$\ell''_X(\bar{x})=-\frac{\bar{x}-n}{(\bar{x}-1)^2}+\frac{n}{\bar{x}}$$

Maybe this is a sign that I'm way off here. Any pointers as to if and where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ell''_X(\theta) = -\frac{n \bar x - n}{(\theta - 1)^2} + \frac{n \bar x}{\theta^2} = n \left( \frac{-\theta^2(\bar x - 1) + \bar x(\theta - 1)^2}{(\theta - 1)^2 \theta^2} \right) = \frac{n(\theta^2 -2 \theta \bar x + \bar x)}{(\theta-1)^2 \theta^2}.$$  Note the denominator is never negative, and $n \ge 1$. So when $\theta = \bar x$, the remaining factor in the numerator is $$\bar x^2 - 2\bar x^2 + \bar x = \bar x - \bar x^2 = \bar x (1-\bar x).$$  Since $\bar x \ge 1$ because $X \ge 1$, it follows that $\bar x (1 - \bar x) \le 0$, with equality attained when $\bar x = 1$.

Comment: That's great. Thank you. I really just fell at the last hurdle as I didnt multiply out fully the second derivative of the likelihood function. Much appreciated!